# Raspberry Pi Model B for a Wireless AP: nl80211 driver initialization failed

Tags: raspbian, wifi, linux, hostapd

I'm trying to setup my Raspberry Pi Model B to act as a standalone Wireless AP using a Ralink MT7601U Wireless Adapter. However, starting hostapd presents me with this error.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf  -d
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:10
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:8
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:9
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities (default) - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities mask (default) - hexdump(len=8): 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 3 to mode 3: -95 (Operation not supported)
nl80211: Try mode change after setting interface down
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 3 to mode 3: -95 (Operation not supported)
nl80211: Interface mode change to 3 from 0 failed
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=3 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211 driver initialization failed.
hostapd_interface_deinit_free(0xf94cf8)
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: num_bss=1 conf->num_bss=1
hostapd_interface_deinit(0xf94cf8)
wlan0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->DISABLED
hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss wlan0
wlan0: AP-DISABLED 
hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0xf95a48 (wlan0))
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlan0 wasn't started
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: driver=(nil) drv_priv=(nil) -> hapd_deinit
hostapd_interface_free(0xf94cf8)
hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0xf95a48
hostapd_cleanup_iface(0xf94cf8)
hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0xf94cf8)
hostapd_cleanup_iface: free iface=0xf94cf8
```

Here is my /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf:

```
interface=wlan0
driver=nl80211
ssid=TestSSID        
hw_mode=g
channel=7
wmm_enabled=0
macaddr_acl=0
auth_algs=1
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0
```

Any help would be appreciated, and I'm happy to provide more info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important messages seem to be:

```
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 3 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 3 to mode 3: -95 (Operation not supported)
nl80211: Interface mode change to 3 from 0 failed
nl80211: Could not configure driver mode
```

For my interpretation `hostapd` tries to set the interface to mode 3 (AP) that is an access point (line 1). But the driver claims **Operation not supported** (line 2). It seems that the *Ralink MT7601U Wireless Adapter* does not support an access point. Check with:

```
rpi ~$ iw phy phy0 info
```

You will get a bunch of information from the *MT7601U*. Just look at the section **Supported interface modes:**. For comparison here are the modes of my RPi 3B+:

```
rpi ~$ iw phy phy0 info
[..]
    Supported interface modes:
             * IBSS
             * managed
             * AP
             * P2P-client
             * P2P-GO
             * P2P-device
[..]
```

Here you will find mode **AP**.

Comment: the original Pi model B is known as a Pi Model B without the number - wikipedia is not the best source of information about such things - [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/revision-codes/README.md) would be my go to reference for such details

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks, I have removed that part about versions.

Comment: @Ingo with `mt7601`, Can you say that, Is it driver issue or hardware has no feature ? about `AP` mode.

Comment: @Nullpointer With the command `iw` you ask the hardware about its features. If you don't find **AP** as supported interface mode, then this mode is not supported by the hardware, e.g. `mt7601`. It is not a driver issue.

Comment: @Ingo But In windows, AP working fine and able to `hotspot feature : yes` in cmd. If `AP` feature is not in hardware then how it's work in Windows !

Comment: @Nullpointer I do not have a `mt7601` adapter available. What supported modes are reported by `iw`?

Comment: @Ingo IN `iw list`, showing Managed and monitor mode only but `AP` working fine in windows & many user are using AP in linux too. with this, I'm confuse. Looking proper driver version and linux kernel version which supported AP+monitor mode (can say master). If master mode enable in linux then i can fluxion for wifi captive portal.

Comment: "*many user are using AP in linux too*" - so what's the problem with your and *SilverMights* adapter? You should create a new question. Maybe you will find a user who have made it working.